# MS chart zoom the chart to a region

Tags: mschart

I created a test project where I have a Chart on a .net core 3 winforms project. I also have a data grid that shows related data, I would like to click on the row in my grid and then Zoom into that region on the chart.

I have the DataPoint and know the duration however how to zoom into to that timespan without loosing the Hight of my YAxis?

This Zooms but also cuts of the YAxis work

```
DataPoint dp = LocationOnChart((double)td.Bar.Close, td.Date.AddSeconds(-5));
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0;

chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = false;
chart.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = false;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ScrollBarButtonStyles.SmallScroll;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSize = 0;





chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = dp.XValue;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Position = dp.YValues[0];
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize = (td.Ended.Value-td.Date).TotalSeconds+5;            
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSizeType  =  DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Scroll(td.Date);
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(dp.XValue,chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize,DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds);

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.MinSize = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
```

The method LocationOnChart is defined like this:

```
private DataPoint LocationOnChart(double price, DateTime time)
{
    var y = TradeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ValueToPosition(price);
    var x = TradeChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ValueToPosition(time.ToOADate());
    return new DataPoint(x, y);
}
```

Comment: I am unable to compile this. What does `LocationOnChart` do? What is the `td` variable? Also, could you include some sample Series and Datapoints?

Comment: @JorisJ1, added the code to the chart, you could substitute it with a hit test, it's just a DataPont